# table-cell / table / table-cell . Can't center vertically the middle element

Tags: css

I'm using a table aproach to automatic dimension for 3 elements.
I like the middle gets all the remaining space - the first and last cell.
OK, This works using table / table-cell - table - table-cell.

But I'm unable to set vertical aligment for central cell ?

```
<div style="display: table; width: 163px; height: 80px;">

 <div style="display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle; width: 1px;">c1</div>

 <div style="display: table;>
    <div style="display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle; width: 100%;">
    <div>c2</div>
    </div>
 </div>

 <div style="display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle; width: 1px;">c3<div>

</div>
```

I have tried a lot of styles with the '`c2`' cell and its parents without success.
Have I to give vertical size to the  central '`table`' column?

I want a solution for this approach (table elements style)

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make central cell `display: table-cell` also with `vertical-align: middle`:

```html
<div style="display: table; width: 163px; height: 80px; background: coral;">
    <div style="display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle; width: 1px; background: #DDD;">c1</div>
    <div style="display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle;">
        <div>
            <div>c2</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div style="display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle; width: 1px; background: #DDD;">
        c3
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: So the trick is use a table-cell but without define width ? So easy ? I have spent a lot of time using a table container ....  This approach gives the same result for vertical dimension (that is table-row approach)?

Comment: The trick is to use `table-cell` because you should not have `display: table` where `table-cell` is expected.

Comment: please can you view this question "Automatic Layout for 2 columns / 3 vertical divs wrong behaviour" I have asked today. Sorry  ... and thks